# Pyramid: resource tree in URL Dispatch(hybrid) application

Tags: python, pyramid

I am trying to implement dynamic ACLs(including row-level security) in URL Dispatch app.
Defining Root factory only doesn't seem to be sufficient as I need to perform individual authz checks for each secured endpoint. My setup looks as follows(I was using [pyramid docs](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html) and [mmerickel's tutorials](https://github.com/mmerickel/pyramid_auth_demo) as a guide):

`config.py`

```
...
settings = config.registry.settings
config = Configurator(settings=settings, root_factory=RootPermissionFactory)
config.set_authentication_policy(CustomAuthenticationPolicy(settings))
config.set_authorization_policy(ACLAuthorizationPolicy())
...
```

`views.py`

```
#import ...

@view_defaults(renderer='json', permission='secured')
class RecordsView(object):
    ...

   @view_config(request_method='GET', route_name='records_by_id')
   def get(self):
        record = self.request.context.data
        if not record:
            return HTTPNotFound()
        return record

    @view_config(request_method='GET', route_name='records')
    def get_by_owners(self):
        owner_uids = self.request.params.mixed()['owner_uids']
        return records_service.get_records(owner_uids=owner_uids)

def includeme(config):
    config.add_route('records', '/records', factory=RecordsResource)
    config.add_route('records_by_id', 'records/{record_id}', factory=RecordFactory, traverse='{record_id}')
```

`authorization.py`

```
class RootPermissionFactory(object):
    __name__ = None
    __parent__ = None

    def __acl__(self):
        return [
            (Allow, 'authenticated_principal', 'secured'),
        ]

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request


class RecordFactory(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        record_data = records_service.get_record(key)
        owner = record_data.get('owner_uid')
        return RecordContext(self.request, owner, record_data)


class RecordContext(object):
    def __acl__(self):    
        owner_principal = 'u:{owner}'.format(owner=self.owner)
        return [
            (Allow, owner_principal, 'secured'),
        ]

    def __init__(self, request, owner, record_data):
        self.request = request
        self.owner = owner
        self.data = record_data


class RecordsResource(object):
    def __acl__(self):
        request_params = self.request.params.mixed()
        request_owner_uids = request_params['owner_uids']
        authorized_owner_uids = owners_api_service.get_authorized_owners(self.request.user['auth_data'])
        return [(Allow, 'authenticated_principal', 'secured')]\
            if set(authorized_owner_uids) == set(request_owner_uids) else []

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
```

My questions are following:

- is it acceptable to utilize row-level security checks without having Model layer? i.e. there is no ORM set up for Records data and there is also no plain Model to put persisted data into, so I have to use 'fake' `RecordContext` class to attach `__acl__` rules and pass data to the view
- is it acceptable to treat `/records` endpoint as a Resource despite the fact it is not a resource from Traversal perspective and relies on query parameters rather than path sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to both of your question is: if it works for you then it's totally acceptable. I've found a lot of success treating URLs as resources as a general pattern to the extent that I have a some tooling to avoid using `route_name`. For example:

```
config.add_route('records', '/records', factory=RecordsResource, use_global_views=True)
config.add_route('records_by_id', 'records/{record_id}', factory=RecordFactory, traverse='{record_id}', use_global_views=True)

@view_config(context=RecordsResource, renderer='json')
def records_view(request):
    return {}

@view_config(context=RecordContext, renderer='json')
def record_view(request):
    return {}
```